# Create knockout binding from observable array to select option

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am relatively new to javascript and am currently learning knockout.

I need to be able to bind a set of values from an observable array to the different options in an html  tag.

Can someone maybe post an example of how this would be accomplished? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of examples here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html